# PathParam in RESTFul ws

Tags: rest, restful-url, path-parameter

I need to use as PathParam the path of a file, how can I do?
Should I use URLEncode e URLDecode? Can someone give me an example?

The structure of my ws is:

```
@Path("/{filePath}")
public Response convert(@PathParam("filePath") String filePath) throws Throwable 
{ 
    ..
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want it to be A File's path?   @Path is used to give the path of a RESTful call or inventory and it's relative to the App's path defined in the web.xml under <servlet-mapping> tag

Comment: I need to pass the file path to the rest service. Recovered files should I do operations on it

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.*` regex for the pathParam. Otherwise jax-rs will only expect one segment. Then resolve the path against your base-directory.

```
@GET
@Path("/backup/{filePath : .*}")
public Response convert(@PathParam("filePath") String filePath) {
    java.nio.file.Path absolutePath = Paths.get("/path/to/backup", filePath);
    return Response.ok(absolutePath.toString()).build();
}
```

`Paths.get("C:/path/to/backup", filePath)` should work if you are using windows. (Untested)

**Unrelated:** I don’t see a reason for throwing a `Throwable`.

Comment: I would imagine that's because there's never a reason to throw a Throwable. :-)